# Simple.Data Distinct with InMemoryAdapter

Tags: simple.data

I'm using Simple.Data and its InMemoryAdapter to write some tests.
The code below is from one of my tests. The test should result in 1 value "Atlanta" being returned, however I get Atlanta twice. I'm wondering if I'm using InMemoryAdapter of Distinct incorrectly?

```
var adapter = new InMemoryAdapter();
Database.UseMockAdapter(adapter);

var db = Database.Open();
db.ParentRegionList.Insert(Id: 1, RegionName: "Dublin");
db.ParentRegionList.Insert(Id: 2, RegionName: "Atlanta");
db.ParentRegionList.Insert(Id: 3, RegionName: "Atlanta");
db.ParentRegionList.Insert(Id: 4, RegionName: "Killarney");
db.ParentRegionList.Insert(Id: 5, RegionName: "Bournemouth");

var result = db.ParentRegionList.All()
    .Where(db.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Like("At%"))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(db.ParentRegionList.RegionName).Take(10)
    .ToScalarList<string>();
```

I've also tried:

```
var result = db.ParentRegionList.All()
    .Where(db.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Like("At%"))
    .Select(db.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Distinct()).Take(10)
    .ToScalarList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second format is correct, I had similar problem. Instead of using a cast as
`ToScalarList<string>()` try creating a dummy type, eg. "Region" that has a string property with name RegionName and cast as: `ToList<Region>()`